# Neo V with 4.0 ICS update -- battery problem

Tags: updates, battery-life, internet, data-connection, sony-xperia-neo-v

My Sony Xperia Neo V battery performance has gone down very badly after upgrading to ICS.

It mainly happens when I have my mobile data/internet turned on. How can I improve the battery performance?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try managing battery life with [JuiceDefender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender), which does a great job at disconnecting data connections when not needed and turning it back on when needed. I can personally attest to this fact although I use gingerbread on my Xperia Neo V. Give it a shot and see